# Processing. Even though the array content has changed, what is being drawn with draw() method doesn't change

Tags: java, processing

**constants**

```
public final int DIMENSIONS = 4;
public final int MOVE_RIGHT = 1;
public final int MOVE_LEFT = 2;
public final int MOVE_UP = 3;
public final int MOVE_DOWN = 4;
```

**main**

```
PuzzleFrame board;

void setup(){
  size(401,401);
  board = new PuzzleFrame();
  background(100);
}

void draw(){
  background(100);
  board.draw();
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if(key == CODED)
  {
    if(keyCode == RIGHT) board.moveTile(MOVE_RIGHT);
    if(keyCode == LEFT) board.moveTile(MOVE_LEFT);
    if(keyCode == UP) board.moveTile(MOVE_UP);
    if(keyCode == DOWN) board.moveTile(MOVE_DOWN);
  }
}
```

**class that creates puzzle frame**

```
class PuzzleFrame{
  private Tile[][] puzzleFrame;
  private Tile[][] solvedPuzzleFrame;

  public PuzzleFrame()
  {
    puzzleFrame = new Tile[DIMENSIONS][DIMENSIONS];
    solvedPuzzleFrame = new Tile[DIMENSIONS][DIMENSIONS];
    int tileNumber = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < DIMENSIONS; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < DIMENSIONS; j++)
      {
        puzzleFrame[i][j] = new Tile(tileNumber, j*100, i*100);
        solvedPuzzleFrame[i][j] = new Tile(tileNumber, j*100, i*100);
        tileNumber++;
      }
    }
  }

  public void draw()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < DIMENSIONS; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < DIMENSIONS; j++)
      {
        puzzleFrame[i][j].draw();
      }
    }
  }

  public void moveTile(int side)
  {
    if(isMoveAllowed(side))
    {
      switch(side)
      {
        case MOVE_RIGHT:
        {
          for(int i = 0; i < DIMENSIONS; i++)
          {
            for(int j = 0; j < DIMENSIONS; j++)
            {
              if(puzzleFrame[i][j].getTileNumber() == DIMENSIONS*DIMENSIONS)
              {
                Tile tempTile = puzzleFrame[i][j];
                puzzleFrame[i][j] = puzzleFrame[i][j-1];
                puzzleFrame[i][j-1] = tempTile;
                System.out.println("right");
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          break;          
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private boolean isMoveAllowed(int side)
  {
    switch(side)
    {
      case MOVE_RIGHT:
      {
        for(int i = 0; i < DIMENSIONS; i++)
        {
          for(int j = 0; j < DIMENSIONS; j++)
          {
            if(puzzleFrame[i][j].getTileNumber() == DIMENSIONS*DIMENSIONS)
            {
              if(j > 0) return true;
            }
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

**tile class which is used for to create puzzle Frame**

```
class Tile{

  private final int mTileNumber;
  private final int width = 100;
  private final int height = 100;
  private String number = "";
  private int xpos;
  private int ypos;
  private int xOffSet;
  private int yOffSet;

  public Tile(int tileNumber, int xpos, int ypos)
  {
    mTileNumber = tileNumber;
    number += tileNumber;
    textSize(64);
    this.xpos = xpos; this.ypos = ypos;
    xOffSet = 30;
    yOffSet = 70;
    if(mTileNumber >= 10)
    {
      xOffSet = 10;
    }
  }

  public void draw()
  {
    if(mTileNumber == DIMENSIONS*DIMENSIONS)
    {
    }
    else
    {
      strokeWeight(2);
      fill(255);
      rect(xpos, ypos, width, height);
      fill(0);
      text(number, xpos+xOffSet, ypos+yOffSet);
    }
  }

  public int getTileNumber()
  {
    return mTileNumber;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make 15 puzzle game but the problem that I came across is that when I press arrow key RIGHT, contents of the puzzleFrame array change (I checked it in Eclipse via debugger) but in processing the image drawn remains the same. For now my code only consists of a function that allows to slide tile to the right. I honestly don't understand why the image remains the same even though the contents of the array have changed.

Comment: Perhaps surprising, you shouldn't just "draw()" (like calling a function in an old FORTRAN program).  Instead, you have to have an *event* handler that responds to a graphics "paint" event.  The *event handler* is where you should do all your drawing.  Your key handler can invoke a graphics "invalidte" to trigger a redraw event.  Here's a good tutorial: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Comment: I found a problem, even though contents of the array change, the coordinates of each tile stay the same, hence, image stays the same. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @paulsm4 this is Processing, not plain Java. There very much is a global draw() that you get to call, and a redraw() that you call in event handling functions (also presupplied). See http://processing.org

Comment: oh, also @user1796741, visibility is not part of the Processing API. While they work because it runs through javac on compile in the PDE, any public/private/protected marking is not actually Processing code, but mixed Processing+Java

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question but how are you avoiding a compiler error in your Tile class during the assignment: mTileNumber = tileNumber 
You declared mTileNumber as a final variable so you shouldn't be able to reassign it to anything.

Comment: a final is a variable whose value will not change, after assignment. His code doesn't assign, only declare, so the first assignment is allowed, after that any attempts to change it a "may already be assigned" compiler exception